# display block not working no float clear both

Tags: css

I want my Superman below overline also I want container to stretch as long as the superman is so superman is always one line. This is so stressful hahaha. I read through most SO question is tells me to clearfix and clear both and i know that div defaults to block I dont know what to do anymore. cry cry. Sorry if this is duplicate or anything I come from Photoshop Island.

```css
    body {background-color: darkslategrey;}
    
    .img
            {
                 display:inline-flex;
                 width:50;
                 height:50;
                 margin: auto; 
            }
    .overline
            {    display: inline-block; 
                 vertical-align:top; 
                 font-family: 'Helvetica'; 
                 padding-left: 5px;
                 padding-top: 5px;
                 font-size: .75em; 
                 text-transform: uppercase;
                 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
                 height: auto;    
            }
    
    .content
            {    display: inline-block; 
                 vertical-align:bottom; 
                 font-family: 'Helvetica'; 
                 padding-left: 5px;
                 padding-top: 5px;
                 font-size: 1em; 
                 text-transform: uppercase;
                 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
                 height: auto;
            }
    .container
            {
                display:inline-flex; 
                background-color: #fff; 
                vertical-align: top; 
                margin: auto; 
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px;
                
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13046668/41792152-165b8206-7682-11e8-8182-dad5d193b494.png" class="img"><!--
--><div class="container">   
    <div class="overline" style="clear: both">overline</div> 
    <br>
    <div class="content" style="clear: both">superman is back</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flex-direction: column on the container div

Removed the br tag.

No need of clear both

Removed the width on container tag

```css
body {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}

.img {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  margin: auto;
}

.overline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: .75em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13046668/41792152-165b8206-7682-11e8-8182-dad5d193b494.png" class="img">
  <!--
-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="overline">overline</div>
    <div class="content">superman is back</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ill look into it tmr. I gave up and now im going to sleep.

Comment: so the width causes my superman to not go below is because I specified the width and displa:block is not enough to make it go below so i need to set flex dirction to column? Why wouldn't display block work though? Anyway thx for the answer. Works perfectly

Comment: you are using inline-block, not block. try using display: block, may be it will work. i cant test it right now, not on my machine right now!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with your width and height of the container.. BUT, if it's `width:200px;` and `height:50px;` that you want, then I made it fit to that size.

There was quite a bit that I changed to make this code look more clean. The big things were:

- Added the image inside of the container div, instead of outside. (This created the `margin:auto;` that you put in your `.container`.. Thus making the container in the center of the web page).. Not sure if that's what you intended, but it now works correctly.. IF you don't want it in the middle, then just take out `margin:auto;` from `.container`
- Took out a lot of unneeded css. (Or replaced.. EX. `display:block;`. I made it block to make sure the divs went top to bottom)
- Added a `float:left;` to `.img` (This brings your overline and content to the right of the image)

```css
    body {background-color: darkslategrey;}
    
    .img{
      width:50;
      height:auto;
      float:left;
      padding-right:5px;
    }
    .overline{    
      display:block;
      font-family: 'Helvetica'; 
      font-size: .75em; 
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .content{    
      display:block;
      font-family: 'Helvetica'; 
      font-size: 1em; 
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .container{
      background-color: #fff; 
      margin: auto; 
      width:200px;
      height:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">   
  <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13046668/41792152-165b8206-7682-11e8-8182-dad5d193b494.png" class="img"/>
  <div class="overline">overline</div> 
  <div class="content">superman is back</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```